# R - Reshape - Melt Error

Tags: r, reshape, melt

I am trying to melt a data frame and I get this weird error. Any ideas why?

```
str(zx7)
'data.frame':   519 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ calday.new: Date, format: "2011-01-03" "2011-01-04" "2011-01-05" "2011-01-06" ...
 $ A20    : Time-Series  from 1 to 519: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ B20    : Time-Series  from 1 to 519: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ C20    : Time-Series  from 1 to 519: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ D20    : Time-Series  from 1 to 519: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...

zx7.melt <- melt(zx7, id=c("calday.new"))
Error in `[<-.ts`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : only replacement of elements is allowed
```

Comment: @Which version of reshape2 do you use? I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: @agstudy, the correct question would be "which version of reshape do you use?" See my response.

Answer (score 2):

I don't konw how did you create your structure, but when I do this , it works for me

```
zx7 <- data.frame( calday.new=seq(from = as.Date('2011-01-03'),by=1,length.out=519),
                   A20=ts(rep(0,519)),
                   B20=ts(rep(0,519)),
                   C20=ts(rep(0,519)),
                   D20=ts(rep(0,519)))
```

I create the same structure as above :

```
str(zx7)
'data.frame':   519 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ calday.new: Date, format: "2011-01-03" "2011-01-04" "2011-01-05" ...
 $ A20       : Time-Series  from 1 to 519: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ B20       : Time-Series  from 1 to 519: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ C20       : Time-Series  from 1 to 519: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
 $ D20       : Time-Series  from 1 to 519: 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 ...
```

Then I melt :

```
head(melt(zx7, id=c("calday.new")))
  calday.new variable value
1 2011-01-03      A20     0
2 2011-01-04      A20     0
3 2011-01-05      A20     0
4 2011-01-06      A20     0
5 2011-01-07      A20     0
6 2011-01-08      A20     0
```

Comment: You get my +1 too, because you took the time to recreate the dataset and your comment to the original question raised a flag in my mind that "Who said anything about 'reshape2'?" Nice work.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the old "reshape" package's `melt()` function does not know what to do when it encounters an object with the class `ts`.

So, you have two obvious options (though perhaps there are more):

1. `unclass` the variables that are currently classed as `ts` before you `melt()` your data:

   ```
   zx7b <- zx7         # Make a backup, just in case
   library(reshape)    # Notice this is "reshape", not "reshape2"
   head(melt(zx7b, id=c("calday.new"))) # Doesn't work
   # Error in `[<-.ts`(`*tmp*`, ri, value = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,  : 
   #   only replacement of elements is allowed

   ## Unclass the relevant columns from your data.frame
   zx7b[sapply(zx7b, is.ts)] <- lapply(zx7b[sapply(zx7b, is.ts)],
                                       unclass)
   head(melt(zx7b, id=c("calday.new")))
   #   calday.new variable value
   # 1 2011-01-03      A20     0
   # 2 2011-01-04      A20     0
   # 3 2011-01-05      A20     0
   # 4 2011-01-06      A20     0
   # 5 2011-01-07      A20     0
   # 6 2011-01-08      A20     0
   ```
2. Upgrade to "reshape2" instead, and no unclassing is required.

   ```
   library(reshape2) # Notice that this is reshape2!
   head(melt(zx7, id=c("calday.new"))) # Melt the original data.frame
   #   calday.new variable value
   # 1 2011-01-03      A20     0
   # 2 2011-01-04      A20     0
   # 3 2011-01-05      A20     0
   # 4 2011-01-06      A20     0
   # 5 2011-01-07      A20     0
   # 6 2011-01-08      A20     0
   ```

I haven't taken the time to do it, but you can check the code for the `melt.data.frame` methods for `melt()` from each version of the "reshape" packages and see where the differences lie. Install both packages and then type `reshape2:::melt.data.frame` and `reshape:::melt.data.frame` to see the underlying functions.

Comment: +1! First I always find that adding a number to package name (reshape, rowygen,..) not very elegant and source of confusion! I hope that this will be deprecated to avoid such errors! Second I will call you mister reshape! You even convince me to grasp the reshape function of the base package!

Comment: @agstudy, I agree about changing the names for the packages. I understand *why* it was done, but having two packages with similar but not identical functionality and syntax can be confusing.